# Failure on warpPerspective

Tags: android, android-ndk, sift, surf, opencv3.1

I am comparing two images using findHomography(). I have added extra modules from [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) in **OpenCV 3.1.0** to use **Surf** and **Sift** **algorithms** and to compile for latest Android architectures. I can successfully compile the libraries using `ndk-build`.

**Problem:**

While detecting object in scene and computing `warpPerspective`, following exception is thrown on some images:

```
11-10 20:47:30.990 10503-11056/ E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((M0.type() == CV_32F || M0.type() == CV_64F) && M0.rows == 3 && M0.cols == 3) in void cv::warpPerspective(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::Size, int, int, const Scalar&), file /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 6120
    --------- beginning of crash
    11-10 20:47:31.020 10503-11056/ A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 11056 (Thread-31509)
    11-10 20:47:31.122 200-200/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    11-10 20:47:31.122 200-200/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:6.0.1/M4B30X/3237893:user/release-keys'
    11-10 20:47:31.122 200-200/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '11'
    11-10 20:47:31.122 200-200/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
    11-10 20:47:31.122 200-200/? A/DEBUG: pid: 10503, tid: 11056, name: Thread-31509  >>>  <<<
    11-10 20:47:31.122 200-200/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    11-10 20:47:31.149 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 00002b30  r2 00000006  r3 926e0978
    11-10 20:47:31.149 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     r4 926e0980  r5 926e0930  r6 00000000  r7 0000010c
    11-10 20:47:31.149 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     r8 00000047  r9 00000001  sl 00000050  fp 00000001
    11-10 20:47:31.149 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     ip 00000006  sp 926cfc48  lr b6d4fb61  pc b6d51f50  cpsr 400f0010
    11-10 20:47:31.174 200-200/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
    11-10 20:47:31.174 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00041f50  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    11-10 20:47:31.174 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0003fb5d  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
    11-10 20:47:31.174 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0001c30f  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    11-10 20:47:31.174 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000194c1  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
    11-10 20:47:31.174 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000174ac  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    11-10 20:47:31.174 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00666958  /data/app/-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+344)
    11-10 20:47:31.175 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0063d7b0  /data/app/-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE+4)
    11-10 20:47:31.175 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0063d7f0  /data/app/-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (_ZSt9terminatev+16)
    11-10 20:47:31.175 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0063d1cc  /data/app/-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (__cxa_throw+168)
    11-10 20:47:31.175 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 001e477d  /data/app/-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (_ZN2cv5errorERKNS_9ExceptionE+244)
    11-10 20:47:31.175 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 001e48bd  /data/app/-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (_ZN2cv5errorEiRKNS_6StringEPKcS4_i+108)
    11-10 20:47:31.175 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 002ca5fd  /data/app/-2/lib/arm/libopencv_java3.so (_ZN2cv15warpPerspectiveERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayES2_NS_5Size_IiEEiiRKNS_7Scalar_IdEE+356)
    11-10 20:47:31.175 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 00007375  /data/app/-2/lib/arm/libnonfree.so (_Z15detect_featuresP7_JNIEnvP8_jstringS2_i+2844)
    11-10 20:47:31.175 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 022bfd23  /data/app/-2/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x13ce000) (boolean .NonfreeJNILib.detectFeatures(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int)+126)
    11-10 20:47:31.176 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 0258c149  /data/app/-2/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x13ce000) (void .tasks.AdDetectionAsyncTask$1.run()+292)
    11-10 20:47:31.176 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 71c99c67  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1ed6000)
```

**Code:**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d/nonfree.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define  LOG_TAG    "nonfree_jni"
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

jboolean detect_features(JNIEnv * env, jstring scenePath, jstring objectPath) {

    const char *nativeScenePath = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(scenePath, NULL);
    const char *nativeObjectPath = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(objectPath, NULL);

    nativeScenePath = env->GetStringUTFChars(scenePath, 0);
    nativeObjectPath = env->GetStringUTFChars(objectPath, 0);

    (env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(scenePath, nativeScenePath);
    (env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(objectPath, nativeObjectPath);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, "Object path: ----- %s \n", nativeObjectPath);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, "Scene path: ----- %s \n", nativeScenePath);

    Mat img_object = imread( nativeObjectPath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    Mat img_scene = imread( nativeScenePath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );


    if( !img_object.data || !img_scene.data){
        LOGI(" --(!) Error reading images ");
        return false;
    }

        //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
        int minHessian = 400;

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, "Image comparison rows: ----- %d \n", img_object.rows);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, "Image comparison colums: ----- %d \n", img_object.cols);

//        cv::xfeatures2d::SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
        Ptr<cv::xfeatures2d::SurfFeatureDetector> detector = cv::xfeatures2d::SurfFeatureDetector::create(minHessian);

        std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;
        detector->detect( img_object, keypoints_object );
        detector->detect( img_scene, keypoints_scene );

        //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
//        cv::xfeatures2d::SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
        Ptr<cv::xfeatures2d::SurfDescriptorExtractor> extractor = cv::xfeatures2d::SurfDescriptorExtractor::create();

        Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;

        extractor->compute( img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object );
        extractor->compute( img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene );

        //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
        FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
        std::vector< DMatch > matches;
        matcher.match( descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches );

        double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

        //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
        for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
        {
            double dist = matches[i].distance;
            if (dist == 0) continue;
            if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
            if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
        }

        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, "-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist);
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, "-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist);

        //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
        std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

        for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
        {
            if( matches[i].distance <= 0.1 ) //3*min_dist
            {
                good_matches.push_back( matches[i]);
            }
        }

        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, "FLANN total matches -----: %zu \n", matches.size());
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, "FLANN good matches -----: %zu \n", good_matches.size());

        Mat img_matches;
        drawMatches( img_object, keypoints_object, img_scene, keypoints_scene,
                    good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
                    vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

        //-- Localize the object
        std::vector<Point2f> obj;
        std::vector<Point2f> scene;

        for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
        {
            //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
            obj.push_back( keypoints_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
            scene.push_back( keypoints_scene[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
        }

        if (good_matches.size() >= 5)
        {
            Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );

            //-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
            std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
            obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0); obj_corners[1] = cvPoint( img_object.cols, 0 );
            obj_corners[2] = cvPoint( img_object.cols, img_object.rows ); obj_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, img_object.rows );
            std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);

            Mat output, matrix;

            warpPerspective(img_object, output, H, { img_scene.cols, img_scene.rows });

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            detector->detect( output, keypoints_object );

            //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
            //cv::xfeatures2d::SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
            Ptr<cv::xfeatures2d::SurfDescriptorExtractor> extractor = cv::xfeatures2d::SurfDescriptorExtractor::create();

            extractor->compute( output, keypoints_object, descriptors_object );
            extractor->compute( img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene );

            std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch>> matches2;
            BFMatcher matcher;
            matcher.knnMatch(descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches2, 2);
            vector<cv::DMatch> good_matches2;

            for (int i = 0; i < matches2.size(); ++i)
            {
                const float ratio = 0.8; // As in Lowe's paper; can be tuned
                if (matches2[i][0].distance < ratio * matches2[i][1].distance)
                {
                    good_matches2.push_back(matches2[i][0]);
                }
            }

            if (matches2.size() == 0 || good_matches2.size() == 0) {
            LOGI( "End run!\n");
                return false;
            }

            double ratioOfSimilarity =  static_cast<double>(good_matches2.size()) / static_cast<double>(matches2.size());

            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, "Bruteforce total matches -----: %zu \n", matches2.size());
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, "Bruteforce good matches -----: %zu \n", good_matches2.size());
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG, "Bruteforce similarity ratio -----: %f \n", ratioOfSimilarity);

            if(ratioOfSimilarity >= 0.3) {
            LOGI( "End run!\n");
                return true;
            }

            LOGI( "End run!\n");
            return false;

        }
        LOGI( "End run!\n");
        return false;
}
```

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this kept me in pain for many days and I don't want others to go through it.

**Here is the problem:**

`cv::findHomography()` function could return empty homography matrix (0 cols x 0 rows) starting approximately from 2.4.5 release. According to some opinion this seems happen only when `cv::RANSAC` flag is passed.

[Reference](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3057)